# Web API - Multiple parameters as /param1/param2/param3/ not working

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I have a an ASP.NET Web API project where I have a single method in my controller as such ..

```
public IHttpActionResult MyMethod(int param1, int param2, int param3)
{
  var theSum = param1 + param2 + param3;
  return Ok(theSum);
}
```

I have the following route in `RouteConfig.cs`

```
routes.MapRoute(
  name: "MyRoute",
  url: "api/{controller}/{action}/{param1}/{param2}/{param3}",
  defaults: new { controller = "MyController", action = "MyRoute", param1 = UrlParameter.Optional, param2 = UrlParameter.Optional, param3 = UrlParameter.Optional }
  );
```

When I call the API with the following URL everything works as expected ..

```
http://localhost/api/mycontroller/mymethod?param1=2&param2=4&param3=6
```

Yet when I try to call the API as follows I get a `404 - The resource cannot be found` error.

```
http://localhost/api/mycontroller/mymethod/2/4/6/
```

any idea why? I thought I had the route setup properly and since the parameters are .NET primitives I though I could pass them as `param1/param2/param3`

Comment: try nuking the trailing /?

Comment: Just tried removing the trailing `/` and still got the 404

Comment: Your Action = "MyRoute" I believe should be Action = "MyMethod"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using MVC5?  If so I'd suggest using the Route() attribute instead the routes collection, for me at least it is easier to manage.  I was able to get this working with your sample using that approach.

```
[Route("api/values/MyMethod/{param1}/{param2}/{param3}")]
[HttpGet]
public IHttpActionResult MyMethod(int param1, int param2, int param3)
{
    var theSum = param1 + param2 + param3;
    return Ok(theSum);
}
```

And then calling it via http://localhost/api/values/mymethod/2/4/6 properly returned 12.

Comment: By using the Route attribute would I remove the entry for "MyRoute" in the RouteConfig.cs?

Comment: Yeah, remove that and just decorate the methods with your attribute

Comment: That worked! Thanks a bunch! Interesting why the route configuration in `Route.Config` did not work.

Comment: I think that has to do with there being 2 route configs - one for MVC style and one for WebAPI, I think you were pushing your config into the MVC route collections (RouteConfig.cs) instead of the WebApiConfig.cs

Comment: If you add something like             config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "MyRoute",
                routeTemplate: "api/values/mymethod/{param1}/{param2}/{param3}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Values", action = "MyMethod" }
            ); to the WebApiConfig and let your controller know to expect a GET [HttpGet] attribute then it should also work